# p:selectOneMenu field with onChange not refreshing outputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have searched in google and Stack Overflow, and have come to this to try and get it to work however it still doesn't work.

Xhtml:

```
<p:panel id="testRefresh" header="Basic">
    <h:outputText value="#{sBean.headTest}" />
</p:panel>

<p:selectOneMenu  valueChangeListener="#{sBean.handleChange}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cream Latte" itemValue="Cream Latte" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Extreme Mocha" itemValue="Extreme Mocha" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Buena Vista" itemValue="Buena Vista" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update=":testRefresh" process="@this" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

sBean.java

```
private String headTest;

//Getter and Setter for headTest and initialized in @PostSconstruct method

public void handleChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
  headTest = (String) event.getNewValue();
}
```

Also do you know any editor online to test JSF with xhtml and respective bean? Would be easier to test.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi, one question per question is common practice in stackoverflow but the answer to your second question is no. To the first question, why don't you use a value attribute? And is the method actually called with the right value? And you don't have a form? [mcve] please and version info..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the throws InterruptedException in the Bean method, messes xhtml access to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your *.xhtml I added `<h:form></h:form>` and slightly changed your update statement:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="testRefresh" header="Basic">
        <h:outputText value="#{sBean.headTest}"/>
    </p:panel>

    <p:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{sBean.handleChange}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cream Latte" itemValue="Cream Latte"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Extreme Mocha" itemValue="Extreme Mocha"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Buena Vista" itemValue="Buena Vista"/>
        <p:ajax event="change" update="testRefresh"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

> Also do you know any editor online to test JSF with xhtml and respective bean? Would be easier to test.

As far as I know there is no online tool, but you could create a "skeleton" Spring project and test there. A good start to that is the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io).